# I cannot access my second database in Laravel (.env & database.php edited !)

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

**I have a database which runs on local that I created with TablePlus. I can access it without any problem. I tested with Insomnia and I can get the info I need. I search how to connect to a second database that is live. I changed my `.env` file and my `database.php` to create another access to the second database. But I have an error message:**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'host' (using passowrd: YES)
```

where host is the name I found in PHP MyAdmin in the variables tab.

**How can I acccess the second DB ? What am I doing wrong ? Do I need to change the `env('DATABASE_URL')` for the second connection in `database.php` ?**

**.env**:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=first_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

DB_SECOND_CONNECTION=mysql2
DB_SECOND_HOST=host //(again, PHP MyAdmin -> variables tab)
DB_SECOND_PORT=3306
DB_SECOND_DATABASE=second_db
DB_SECOND_USERNAME=*username*
DB_SECOND_PASSWORD=*password*
```

**database.php**:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'first_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
    'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_SECOND_HOST', 'host'), //(again, PHP MyAdmin -> variables tab)
        'port' => env('DB_SECOND_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_SECOND_DATABASE', 'secondd_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_SECOND_USERNAME', 'username'),
        'password' => env('DB_SECOND_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SECOND_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
],
```

Comment: You're using the same environment variables for the mysql2 connection in database.php

Comment: Sorry, it was correct in my code... I edited the question !

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: Clearing the config does not fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the database connection is actually accesable you could try the following.

First clear your config using the following command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Then check if the connection is accesable using the following code:

```
try {
    DB::connection('mysql2')->getPdo();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration. error:" . $e );
}
```

If that doesn't work check if the user has the right permissions.

Comment: I have the same error message `PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'host' (using passowrd: YES)`

Comment: Good to hear that you found a solution, if this awnser helped you mark it as good so others can find a solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Collin above, the root user I was using didn't have the permissions. Creating a new user with all privileges in PHP MyAdmin solved the issue.